# HTML canvas move all elements to event click coords

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I have a bits raining effect made with canvas using this code [script](https://codepen.io/P3R0/pen/MwgoKv)

```
    var c = document.getElementById("c");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

    //making the canvas full screen
    c.height = window.innerHeight;
    c.width = window.innerWidth;

    //chinese characters - taken from the unicode charset
    var chinese = "0 1 ";
    //converting the string into an array of single characters
     chinese = chinese.split("");

    var font_size = 10;
    var columns = c.width/font_size; //number of columns for the rain
     //an array of drops - one per column
     var drops = [];
    //x below is the x coordinate
    //1 = y co-ordinate of the drop(same for every drop initially)
     for(var x = 0; x < columns; x++)
    drops[x] = 1; 

    //drawing the characters
    function draw()
  {
//Black BG for the canvas
//translucent BG to show trail
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05)";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

ctx.fillStyle = "#0F0"; //green text
ctx.font = font_size + "px arial";
//looping over drops
for(var i = 0; i < drops.length; i++)
{
    //a random chinese character to print
    var text = chinese[Math.floor(Math.random()*chinese.length)];
    //x = i*font_size, y = value of drops[i]*font_size
    ctx.fillText(text, i*font_size, drops[i]*font_size);

    //sending the drop back to the top randomly after it has crossed the screen
    //adding a randomness to the reset to make the drops scattered on the Y axis
    if(drops[i]*font_size > c.height && Math.random() > 0.975)
        drops[i] = 0;

    //incrementing Y coordinate
    drops[i]++;
}
}

 setInterval(draw, 33);
```

and I am trying to make an effect when i click on A button, I want for all the bits to move to the button position and i tried the following code but it is not working properly. I tried to stop the bits raining and move all elements from the current position to the click event coords. Any ideas?
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qLnnfwbL/1/)

Comment: what is exactly the issue ? your code seems to work, so what is the excpected behavior

Comment: the effect is now that the bits are becoming lines and the initial bits are still there. The effect should be that the bits are actually going under the button and the container will be clean